# PayPal Encrypted Payments Not Working PHP APACHE XAMPP

Tags: php, paypal, openssl, xampp, payment

I have some code here that is not functioning.

The critical issue here is the SSL encryption through the exec command in PHP.

The part <<*EOF*\n$data\n_EOF_\n is causing an issue as it causes the encryption to fail. I have tried the rest of the command without <<*EOF*\n$data\n_EOF_\n and it worked fine.

**Notes:**

1. I am running on Windows 10, XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2, PHP, and Apache.
2. This is a personal computer.
3. It has the full installation of XAMPP.
4. OpenSSL is enabled.
5. PHP safe_mode is disabled.
6. The paths of OpenSSL and the certificate files are correct.

I have done much research into this issue and could not quite find a reliable solution. I would greatly appreciate some help! Thanks!

```
$types = array('bronze','silver','gold','platinum','diamond');
            if(!in_array($_GET['type'],$types)) {
                die('<error />');
            }
            $type = $_GET['type'];
            if($type == 'bronze') {
                $amount = '15.00';
            } elseif ($type == 'silver') {
                $amount = '25.00';
            } elseif ($type == 'gold') {
                $amount = '50.00';
            } elseif ($type == 'platinum') {
                $amount = '75.00';
            } elseif ($type == 'diamond') {
                $amount = '100.00';
            }
            #Discount Rate
            $discount_rate = '0';
            $IPN_URL = 'https://www.example.net/paypal/ipn';
            $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE = 'C:\\xampp\\example.net\\paypal\\paypal_cert.pem';
            $MY_KEY_FILE = 'C:\\xampp\\example.net\\paypal\\prvkey.pem';
            $MY_CERT_FILE = 'C:\\xampp\\example.net\\paypal\\pubcert.pem';
            $OPENSSL = 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\openssl.exe';

            $form = array(
                'cmd' => '_xclick',
                'amount' => $amount,
                'item_number' => explode('"',$userinfo['external_auth'])[3],
                'discount_rate' => $discount_rate,
                'item_name' => ucfirst($type).' EXAMPLE :: TEST',
                'notify_url' => $IPN_URL,
                'business' => 'example@live.ca',
                'cert_id' => 'SOME_ID_HERE',
                'currency_code' => 'USD',
                'no_shipping' => '1'
            );

            function paypal_encrypt($hash) {
                global $MY_KEY_FILE;
                global $MY_CERT_FILE;
                global $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE;
                global $OPENSSL;

                if (!file_exists($MY_KEY_FILE)) {
                    echo "ERROR: MY_KEY_FILE $MY_KEY_FILE not found\n";
                }
                if (!file_exists($MY_CERT_FILE)) {
                    echo "ERROR: MY_CERT_FILE $MY_CERT_FILE not found\n";
                }
                if (!file_exists($PAYPAL_CERT_FILE)) {
                    echo "ERROR: PAYPAL_CERT_FILE $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE not found\n";
                }


                //Assign Build Notation for PayPal Support
                $hash['bn']= 'domain.PHP_EWP2';

                $data = "";
                foreach ($hash as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value != "") {
                        $data .= "$key=".escapeshellcmd($value)."\n";
                    }
                }

                $openssl_cmd = "($OPENSSL smime -sign -signer $MY_CERT_FILE -inkey $MY_KEY_FILE " .
                                    "-outform der -nodetach -binary <<_EOF_\n$data\n_EOF_\n) | " .
                                    "$OPENSSL smime -encrypt -des3 -binary -outform pem $PAYPAL_CERT_FILE";

                exec($openssl_cmd, $output, $error);

                if (!$error) {
                    return implode("\n",$output);
                } else {
                    return "ERROR: encryption failed";
                }
            };

            $encrypted = paypal_encrypt($form);
            die('<success />'.$encrypted);
```

EDIT:

I am using https://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php as a guide.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using xampp and your notify url has "localhost" in it, you are on another level. If you have a domain masking your xampp server, u can't use that url. Your notify url has to be ip address. ;) Just know I came back to tell you that. Just figured it out myself. If it helped, donate to foziazzubaidi@gmail.com through paypal haha. If it didn't, I've been making websites for a decade now. Send me an email, I'd be happy to help.

PEACE!!!